# Why do cancelled meetings show in Outlook on my boss' iPad but not on my laptop

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, ipad, meetings

I have full Outlook access to my boss' calendar however when meetings are cancelled by either me or the adminstrator in our team, they can still be seen in his iPad, but not in my laptop ie my laptop and his iPad are not syncing in some way on this.

Cancelled meetings are automatically deleted from my laptop but still show in his iPad, just has cancelled at the top.  This makes his diary cluttered and hard to read for him as meeting change all the time.

I'm hoping it’s just a setting thing - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Except for meetings you cancel, does your boss's calendar sync across your computer and mobile device?

If not, as i know, when you use Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync to connect a mobile device to Exchange Online in Microsoft 365, the calendar on the mobile device and the calendar in the Exchange Online mailbox are out of sync.Please check this article：

[Calendar on mobile device isn't synced to the calendar in an Exchange Online mailbox when you use Exchange ActiveSync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/calendars/calendar-on-mobile-device-not-synced-to-online-mailbox)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.